# A rule doesn't appear in the Style tab of Firebug

Tags: css, firebug

i have this [page](http://www.tirengarfio.com/rs2/web/miembros).

> login: maria@mail.com password: m

You can see two selects in the filter for which i have this rule in gente.css:

```
td.select label{

    margin-left:12px;

}
```

The problem: the rule is applied but doesn't appear in the Style tab of Firebug.

Any idea?

Regards

Javi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `<td>` element with the class `select` on that page. Add the class, and you should be good to go.